# Replace text if it matches another piece of text

Tags: php, strpos

So I have the following code to remove "page=" from a string. My problem now is that I want to query through "$qs_final" to check if it contains "price_range" and if so replace it with another piece of text. The price range variable is attached to "attr=" so I can't really use a $_GET request as other information is stored within it. The price_range variable also has the layout of "price_range_20".

```
<?php 
    $querystring = explode("&",$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $qs_nos = 0;
    $qs_final = "";
    while(isset($querystring[$qs_nos])) {
        if(!ereg("page=",$querystring[$qs_nos])) {
            $qs_final .= $querystring[$qs_nos]."&";
        }
        $qs_nos++;
    }
    if (strpos($qs_final,'price_range') !== false) {
        print "true";
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace).

```
$new_string = str_replace($what_to_replace, $what_to_replace_it_with, $old_string);
```

**EDIT:** To replace data, you need [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg-replace). In your case to remove "price_range" and all numbers and underscores directly after it, use this:

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/price_range[0-9_]+/", "", $old_string);
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this. The problem with this is that it only replaces only "price_range" however it missing out the rest of the data such as "20" and returns the following: `attr=price_range_20_510_20_5010`.